# How to import data from Excel into Access and obtaining foreign keys

Tags: excel, ms-access, import, vba

I want to import data from an Excel table into predefined Access tables.  I have 8 tables where 3 of them rely on foreign keys.  So, I want to be able to obtain these foreign keys when importing so the information can be imported properly.

For example, the table tblSubcomponents has the following fields: 
 - SubcomponentID (autonumber)
 - SubcomponentNumber
 - SubcomponentName
 - MaterialField

The field SubcomponentID then is a foreign key on the table tblBrushholderDetails.  Where the fields for this table include: 
 - BHDetailsID (autonumber)
 - BHID (foreign key)
 - SubcomponentID (foreign key)
 - Parts/BH

I have already looked at the thread:  [How to assign foreign keys in Access within imported table from Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26798867/how-to-assign-foreign-keys-in-access-within-imported-table-from-excel).  However, I was looking into doing something more along the lines of INSERT INTO and @@IDENTITY...Is this possible?

Thank you for your input! :)

Answer (score 0):

I use the following code in a similar situation:

```
DB.Execute "insert into [Book to Tax import files] ([file name],[update date]) values (" & "'" & file.Name & "',#" & file.DateLastModified & "#);"
Source = DB.OpenRecordset("SELECT @@IDENTITY")(0)
DoCmd.TransferText , , "Book to Tax import Temp", Source_folder & "\" & file.Name

SQL = "INSERT INTO [Book to Tax Import data] ([source], Account, [Book Balance], [Book Adjustments], [Adjusted Book Balance], [Tax Reclass], [Balance After Tax Reclass], [Tax Adjustments], [Historical tax Adjustments], [Tax Balance] )"
SQL = SQL & "select " & Source & ",trim(F1),F2,F3,F4,F5,F6,F7,F8,F9 FROM [Book to Tax import temp] ;"

DoCmd.RunSQL SQL
DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, "Book to Tax Import Temp"
```

In this case, I basically put the file names into a table with an autonumber primary key.  Then I retrieve that key with the @@Identity, and use it as a foreign key when i append the data into the 2nd table.